# How to remove duplicate columns in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

i have a employee table

```
eid | ename  | deptno
---------------------
1   | ABC    | 10
2   | XYZ    | 20 
3   | PQR    | 10 
4   | BCD    | 20 
5   | CBA    | 10
```

when i try to group by using deptno it shows the deptno in the second column as well as.How do i avoid it?

Comment: what out put exactly you want.Please mention those as well

Answer (score 0):

Once grouped, you have to iterate through element (with `FOREACH`) and project your data with `GENERATE` to select the columns you're interesting in.
Like :

```
res = FOREACH ( GROUP input BY deptno ) {
    GENERATE eid, ename
        , deptno -- you may remove that line if you do not need deptno anymore
    ;
}
```